# No application can perform this action

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery

I want to launch a single Intent to select images from either the Gallery or the Camera. I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27873957/4290431) answer in my application.

I have already tested the code and it was working perfectly fine on my device.
But when I test it today, it was showing dialog box with message "No application can perform this action".

I have looked in my phone camera and gallery both working fine and enabled. Still I am having this issue in my phone.

I have also looked on the internet but not able to find any solution. Hope you guys can help me.

P.S. I am using Sony Xperia M(Android version 4.3) for testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - getting an error "no application can perform this action" while trying to send an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779077/android-getting-an-error-no-application-can-perform-this-action-while-trying)

Comment: My question is not for sending emails. Please read the question properly. @DhawalSodhaParmar

Comment: its not about sending email, pick image whatever... its about setType("text/plain"); in your intent. use appropriate for your intent

Comment: It doesn't solve entire issue. I am able to see camera now but not gallery. @DhawalSodhaParmar

Comment: I resolved issue by setting setType("image/*"); Thanks.

Comment: Clear the cache and clear data of camera application then try out.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue by setting `setType("image/*");`

Comment: care to comment whoever did downvote for this answer? Because my code is perfectly working and also it is same in the code which i refer to.